# Is it 'plate tectonics' OR 'tectonics plate'?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I saw this headline on ny times:

> Venus lacks **plate tectonics**. But it has something much more quirky

source: [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/06/22/science/venus-tectonic-activity.html)

It got me wondering the folloing, among the words 'plate' and 'tectonics' the later is more accurate to be used to describe something. I mean something has to exists to be tectonics but a plate can exixts regardless of being tectonics or not right? so shouldn't it be:

'Venus lacks tectonics plate. But it has something much more quirky' intead?

Answer (score 3):

“[Plate tectonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics)” is correct. The phrase does not describe an *object*, but a *science* dealing with a certain kind of geological process, involving the interactions of large chunks of a planet’s crust as they ‘float’ on the mantle.